# How to set up a spherically symmetric Fourier transform?

Tags: symbolic, fourier-analysis, piecewise, integral-transforms

I am having trouble figuring out how to set up the Fourier transform to:

```
f[r_] := Piecewise[{{-1/ r, r > a}, {-1/( 2 a) (3 - r^2/a^2), r < a}}]
FourierCosTransform[f[r], r, k, Assumptions -> k > 0]
```

Any help please?

Comment: With `Assumptions -> {r > 0, a > 0}`, `FourierTransform`, `FourierSinTransform`, `FourierCosTransform` can easily calculate the transform, but none of the result matches the given result. Also, imposing `InverseFourierTransform`, `InverseFourierSinTransform`, `InverseFourierCosTransform` on the given solution doesn't reproduce $v_{mc}(r)$, either. Are you sure the given result is correct? What's the definition of Fourier transform used in this case?

Comment: In a Fourier transform r normally goes from - infinity to + infinity.  Is this your case or does r start from 0? There is a pole at r = 0. Which side of the pole should the integration go?

Comment: @xzczd  the result is correct and I am sure. What I know that I am working with 3D FT. I will simplify the above function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Summary:**  To perform the 3D Fourier Transform of a spherically symmetric function $f(r)$ in Mathematica, use the command

```
(4 Pi)/k FourierSinTransform[f[r] r, r, k]
```

(note the additional factor of $r$ in the function being transformed.)

---

This is a standard problem in scattering theory;  one needs to find the transform of the electric potential of a ball of charge with uniform charge density and radius $a$.  The potential given in the problem is the electric potential, though note that it should be
$$
f(r) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{r} & r >a \\ -\frac{1}{2a}\left( 3 - r^2/a^2 \right) & r \leq a \end{cases}.
$$
In Mathematica this is

```
f[r_] = Piecewise[{{-1/r, r > a}, {-1/(2 a) (3 - r^2/a^2), r < a}}]
```

The Fourier transform of this is the 3D integral (up to an overall normalization factor)
$$
\iiint f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}) e^{i(k_x x + k_y y + k_z z)} dx dy dz,
$$
and if you call

```
FourierTransform[f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + y^2]], {x, y, z}, {kx, ky, kz}, Assumptions -> {a > 0}]
```

then Mathematica will valiantly attempt to solve this integral for the Fourier transform instead of $k_x, k_y$, and $k_z$.  I started Mathematica on this task when I started writing this answer;  it took me 15 minutes to write it out, and Mathematica did not find an answer in that time.

Instead, we need to lay a bit of groundwork.  If the potential is spherically symmetric, the above integral can be rewritten as
$$
\iiint f(r) e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d \phi
$$ 
For any particular value of $\vec{k}$, we are free to re-orient our coordinates so that $\vec{k}$ is parallel to the $z$-axis.  In this case, we find that this integral is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^\pi \int_0^\infty f(r) e^{i k r \cos \theta} r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d \phi,
$$ 
where $k = |\vec{k}|$.

The integral over $\phi$ is obvious, and this becomes
$$
2 \pi \int_{0}^\pi \int_0^\infty  f(r) e^{i k r \cos \theta} r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta
$$ 
The integral over $\theta$ is a bit less obvious, but it can also be performed (use a substitution $u = \cos \theta$), yielding
$$
\frac{4 \pi}{k} \int_0^\infty f(r) r  \sin (kr) dr 
$$
This remaining integral can be recognized as the Fourier Sine Transform of the function $r f(r)$, and Mathematica *can* calculate that:

```
(4 Pi / k) FourierSinTransform[f[r] r, r, k, Assumptions -> {a > 0}]

(* (12 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Cos[a k])/(a^2 k^4) - (12 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sin[a k])/(a^3 k^5) *)
```

which is the desired result up to a factor of $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ (which I assume is due to differing conventions surrounding the Fourier Transform) and a sign (which I'm not quite sure about but I wouldn't be surprised if I dropped somewhere.)

Comment: (+1) Great explanation! `FourierParameters -> {1, -1}` gets us a bit closer to the reference (correct sign with a factor of two missing).

Comment: @Michael Thanks so much for what you did and for great explanation.