# 3D Fourier transform of 1/r^2

Tags: physics, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

How can I compute the Fourier Transform of $f(r)=1/r^2$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$?

Comment: Is this a question about the software *Mathematica*?

Comment: @J.M.: Yes, of course, since the `FourierTransform[1/(x^2+y^2+z^2),{x,y,z},{p,q,s}]`command is running without any response on my comp for hours.

Comment: I think your question is not about MA, am I right? If you just want to know the derivation, the best place to look would be some book on theoretical physics. Note that $\frac{1}{r}$ is the Coulomb potential. It Fourier transform is $\frac{4\pi}{q^2}$. Therefore the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{r^2}$ is $\frac{(2\pi)^3)}{4\pi}\frac{1}{q}$.

Comment: @yarchik: Can you kindly give solid math references to your claims (especially, to " It Fourier transform is $\frac {4\pi} {q^2}$")? What do you mean by MA?  About what dimension do you talk?

Comment: @user64494 Well, since I related by comment to some physical interpretation, one could look at the books/articles at the intersection of mathematics and physics. For instance, I find in several papers of Elliott H. Lieb exactly this statement [e.g. Eq.(7.6) in Commun. Math. Phys. 118,177-213 (1988)]. If he is not rigorous, then I do not know who is. But for completeness, there is exactly the same discussion at [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/fourier-transform-of-the-coulomb-potential).

Comment: @yarchik: Thank you. I see the same formal and ungrounded transformations there ($a\to 0$ etc).

Comment: Related:  [How to set up a spherically symmetric Fourier transform?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/205031/)

Comment: BTW, making use of the above thread, one obtains `(4 Pi)/k FourierSinTransform[1/r^2* r, r, k]` which results in `(2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2) Sign[k])/k`. It should be noticed that there is not any singularity in the origin there.

Comment: I'd like to add that the result of `FourierSinTransform[1/r^2* r, r, k]` is not in accordance with [Gelfand and Shilov](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixd7i56n0cz91gt/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-06-12%2017.20.39.png?dl=0) (see line 2).

Answer (score 9):

The Fourier transform will be spherically symmetric, so let's set $\vec{k}$ parallel to the $z$-axis without restriction of generality.

First, generalize the integral to the Fourier transform of $r^{2n}$; we will set $n=-1$ at the end:

```
Assuming[-3/2 < n < -1 && Element[k, Reals],
  Integrate[(x^2+y^2+z^2)^n*Exp[I*k*z], {z, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}]]
(*    -4*π*Abs[k]^(-3-2*n)*Gamma[2+2*n]*Sin[n*π]    *)

Limit[%, n -> -1, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
(*    2*π^2/Abs[k]    *)
```

So the Fourier transform is, taking spherical symmetry back into account,

$$
\mathcal{F}(\vec{k}) = \frac{2\pi^2}{\|\vec{k}\|}
$$

Comment: Also see that [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), especially 502 in the "Formulas for general n-dimensional functions" table.

Comment: Roman(@does not work.) : I don't find this formula in handbooks, textbooks, and Wiki. Think of its scientific publication (preferably in a physic journal).

Comment: Likely 502 has been changed in the latest edit of that Wiki article on 29.05.22. Now 502 refers to Gelfand and Shilov (a screen is made by me). I am going to check the reference.

Comment: Looking in [the original book of Gelfand &Shilov](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixd7i56n0cz91gt/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-06-12%2017.20.39.png?dl=0) , we see in line 2 the Fourier transform of $z^\lambda$ if $\lambda\neq  0,\,\pm1,\, \pm 2\, \dots$. Therefore,  current 502 is not in accordance with Gelfand and Shilov.

Comment: [Formula 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rs1tzgl4uh35xrn/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-06-12%2018.42.15.png?dl=0) on p. 197  of Gelfand and Shilov is wrong if $\lambda=-2$ in view of pole of $\Gamma(z)$ at $z=-1$.

Answer (score 6):

Roman provides a perfect answer to the OP question. However, user64494 has some reservations claiming that the Fourier transform does not exist using as an argument calculations for the $\vec q=(1,1,1)$. Below, I demonstrate that integrals of this kind are computable with Mathematica and, moreover, they are finite.

### Partial case $\vec q=(1,1,1)$

Consider
$$
I(1,1,1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{i(x+y+z)} \,dx\,dy\,dz.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Expanding the exponent and reducing the integral to $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$ we obtain

```
ComplexExpand[Sum[Exp[I (a x + b y + c z)], {a, -1, 1, 2}, {b, -1, 1, 2}, {c, -1, 1, 2}]] // TrigExpand
```

$$8 \cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)$$
It is sufficient to consider just
$$
I(1,1,1)=8 \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz.\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Let us proceed brute force.

I. Integration over $z$

```
Integrate[8 Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {z, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x > 0 && y > 0]
```

$$4\pi \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cos (x) \cos (y)\tag{3a}\label{3a}$$

II. This can be integrated in polar coordinates (first $r$ then $\theta$):

```
Integrate[(4 π Cos[r Cos[θ]] Cos[r Sin[θ]] E^-r , {r, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> θ > 0]
```

$$\frac{16 \pi }{\cos (4 \theta )+7}.\tag{3b}\label{3b}$$

```
  Integrate[16 π/(7 + Cos[4 θ]), {θ, 0, π/2}]
```

$$\frac{2 \pi ^2}{\sqrt{3}}.\tag{3c}\label{3c}$$

Thus, there is no divergency and the answer coincides with Roman's.

### From partial to general case

I have demonstrated that in one particular case of $q$, the integration can be done analytically in the cylindrical coordinate system. Unlike any other approach, I am not performing a regularization of the integral followed by the limit. Indeed, they are very common: for instance in the [answer of Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239714/9469) and in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/fourier-transform-of-the-coulomb-potential). This is the physicists' way of doing the calculations.

However, a regularization is not required and the result can be obtained with very straightforward means, also for any $\vec q\neq0$. This can be done by the reduction to the partial case above. One uses three observations:

1. The Fourier integral is dependent only on the norm of $\vec q$, but not on its direction.
2. By performing rescaling of $x$, $y$, and $z$ it follows that the dependence is $c \lVert\vec{q}\rVert^{-1}$ for $\lVert\vec{q}\rVert\neq0$.
3. The value of the constant is obtained from the partial case \eqref{1} considered above: $\lVert(1,1,1)\rVert=\sqrt{3}$. Thus $c=2\pi^2$ and the final answer is

$$
\frac{2\pi^2}{\lVert\vec{q}\rVert}.\tag{4}\label{4}
$$

But what about the $q=0$ case? Here, the Fourier integral diverges as can be readily shown in spherical coordinates, which is consisted with the equation above.

### Amendment

There have been some criticism from user64494 that I did some questionable implicit limit in the transition from \eqref{1} to \eqref{2}. This was done for pure esthetics and can be avoided as well. Thus constant $c$ can be computed as

$$c=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{i z} \,dx\,dy\,dz.$$

```
i1 = Integrate[Exp[I (x + y + z)]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {z, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> Element[x | y, Reals] && x^2 + y^2 > 0]
c=Integrate[i1, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, ∞, ∞}]
```

$$c=2 \pi ^2$$.

Comment: Replacing $I(1,1,1)$ in your notation by $$8 \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$, you in fact consider $$\lim\limits_{A\to \infty} 8 \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A \frac{\cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ and calculate it. This is not the triple integral under consideration which diverges. BTW, I have never seen any principal values of multple integrals in math literature and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) confirm it.

Comment: yarhik (@ does not work.) Hope  am clear. However don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: In my first comment $8$ in the latter integral should be omitted. It should be $$ \lim\limits_{A\to \infty} \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A \frac{\cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ there. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: yarcik:I repeat replacing $I(1,1,1)$ in your notation by
$$8 \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz $$
, you in fact consider
$$ \lim\limits_{A\to \infty} \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A \int_{-A}^A \frac {e^{i(x+y+z)}}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$
and calculate it. This is not the triple integral under consideration which diverges. 
BTW, I have never seen any principal values of multple integrals in math literature and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) confirm it.

Comment: yarchik: Please comment my answer as a comment to the answer of me.

Comment: yarchik:1) You computed the iterated integral $$ 8 \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos (x) \cos (y) \cos (z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz.$$.

Comment: yarcik:  2) Up to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) "The definition of the Fourier transform by the integral formula

$${\displaystyle {\hat {f}}(\xi )=\int _{\mathbb {R} ^{n}}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi \cdot x}\,dx}{\displaystyle {\hat {f}}(\xi )=\int _{\mathbb {R} ^{n}}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi \cdot x}\,dx}$$
is valid for Lebesgue integrable functions", but the integral $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ diverges.

Comment: Yarchik: "This was done for pure esthetics and can be avoided as well" is ungrounded claim. The triple iimproper ntegral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{i z} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ diverges.

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, I do not understand what exactly is ungrounded, that it was pure esthetics choice, or that it can be avoided?

Comment: yarchik: Both, `Integrate[
 Exp[I (x + y + z)]/(x^2 + y^2 + 
    z^2), {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`produces "Integrate::idiv: Integral of \[Pi]/Sqrt[x^2+z^2] does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.".

Comment: @user64494 Actually, this is my last time I participate in such non-reciprocal discussion. So far, there have'nt been any solid arguments from your side. It is either something that you "have never seen", or some wiki-citation, or this time you are verifying the convergence of the triple integral with mathematica (!!!). MA does not have a notion of multiple integrals, only the iterated ones. This have already been pointed out several times here. And the reason is simple-MA is a computational software, not a human mathematician. Why don't you provide your super rigorous proof?

Answer (score 5):

There is a well known trick that makes this and some related problems relatively straightforward. Namely, using the identity:

$\frac{1}{r}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tr}dt$

and rearranging the order of integration, the 3D Fourier transform becomes separable;

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} e^{-i (u x + v y + w z)} dx dy dz = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t x^2 -i u x} dx \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t y^2 -i v y} dy \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t z^2 -i w z} dz \right) dt$

Now, the product of three Gaussians in real space transforms trivially into a product of three Gaussians in Fourier space. Rearranging and simplifying we are left with the integral:

$\pi^{3/2} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-3/2} e^{-\frac{1}{4t} (u^2 + v^2 + w^2)} dt$

If we are solving this by hand, we can perform the change of variables $t=s^{-2}$ and integrate the resulting Gaussian to get the expected result:

$2 \pi^{3/2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{4} s^2 (u^2 + v^2 + w^2)} ds = \frac{2\pi^2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}}$

The following Mathematica expression will compute the correct answer:

```
Assuming[
    Element[u | v | w, Reals], 
    Integrate[
        FourierTransform[
            Exp[-t (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], {x, y, z}, {u, v, w}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}
        ],
    {t, 0, Infinity}]
]
```

Comment: The rearranging the order of integration in an improper integral should be grounded. For example, that iterated integral `Integrate[
 x*Exp[-x^2]*Exp[y^2], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` results in zero though the double integral diverges.

Comment: That other comment aside, regarding "only scaled by a $(2\pi)^{-3/2}$ factor because of the different definition of the Fourier transform used by Mathematica", this is where you use the `FourierParameters` option: `Assuming[(u | v | w) ∈ Reals, Integrate[FourierTransform[Exp[-t (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], {x, y, z}, {u, v, w}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], {t, 0, Infinity}]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way:

```
$Version
(*"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"*)

r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
F = FourierTransform[1/r^2, {x, y}, {u, v}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
(*(4 π MeijerG[{{0, 0}, {}}, {{}, {}}, 
4/((u^2 + v^2) z^2)])/((u^2 + v^2) z^2)*)

FullSimplify[FourierTransform[F, z, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], 
Assumptions -> {u, v, w} ∈ Reals]

(*(2 π^2)/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2 + w^2]*)
```

Comment: Interesting. Side note: _v12.3_ can also handle this, but _v9.0.1_ crashes after running for several minutes at the first `FourierTransform[…]`.

Comment: `F` is a 2D Fourier transform, where `z` is treated as a paremeters. It is unclear whether the composition of `FourierTransform[F, z, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}],   Assumptions -> {u, v, w} \[Element] Reals]` with `F` is the 3D Fourier transform from the question. It should be noticed that many Fourier transforms are implemented in CASes as table values. It would be useful to find `F` in handbooks.

Comment: I'd like to add that `FourierTransform[1/r^2, {x, y}, {u, v}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]` with `r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];` does not exist in traditional math because $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dxdy$ diverges for each real value of $z$..

Answer (score 0):

This Fourier transform does not exist. Let us make use of its definition as the triple integral (see the documentation to `FourierTransform` ) and switch to [the spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{i(px+qy+sz)} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ becomes, taking into account the Jacobian, $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi }\sin \theta e^{ir(\sin \theta \cos \phi\, p+ \sin \theta \sin \phi\, q +\sin \theta\, s)} \,d\phi\,d\theta\,dr. $$
Now that Mathematca code

```
Integrate[ Sin[\[Theta]]* Exp[I*r*(Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]*p + Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]*q +
Cos[\[Theta]]*s)], {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {r >= 0, {p, q, s} \[Element] Reals, \[Theta] >= 
0, \[Theta] <= Pi}]
```

results in

> `2 E^(I r s Cos[\[Theta]]) \[Pi] BesselJ[0,  Sqrt[p^2 + q^2] r Sin[\[Theta]]] Sin[\[Theta]]`

and the integral of this over $r$ from zero to infinity diverges if the Mathematica's integration and my transformations are correct.
For example, putting `p=1,q=1,s=1`, we have

```
Integrate[ Normal[Series[
2 E^(I r  Cos[\[Theta]]) \[Pi] BesselJ[0, 
  Sqrt[2]* r Sin[\[Theta]]] Sin[\[Theta]], {r, Infinity, 2}, 
Assumptions -> {\[Theta] >= 0, \[Theta] <= Pi}]] // Simplify, 
{r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {\[Theta] >= 0, \[Theta] <= Pi}]
```

which results in

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of -((E^(I r Cos[[Theta]]) Sqrt[[Pi]] Cos[Sqrt[2] r Sin[[Theta]]] Sqrt[Csc[[Theta]]/r^3])/(4 2^(3/4)))+<<1>>/(4 2^<<1>>)+2 2^(1/4) E^(I r Cos[[Theta]]) Sqrt[[Pi]] r Sqrt[Csc[[Theta]]/r^3] Sin[[Theta]] Sin[[Pi]/4+Sqrt[2] r Sin[[Theta]]] does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

EDIT.A typo in the result of `Integrate[ Sin[\[Theta]]* Exp[I*r*(Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]*p + Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]*q + Cos[\[Theta]]*s)], {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi},  Assumptions -> {r >= 0, {p, q, s} \[Element] Reals, \[Theta] >=  0, \[Theta] <= Pi}]`. The latest integration is added. Many thanks to @yarchik for his valuable comment.

Comment: Additionally, the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac 1 {x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ obviously diverges so the Fourier transform under consideration does not exist in the sense of traditional math.

Comment: I'd like to add that the`FourierTransform[1/(x^2+y^2+z^2),{x,y,z},{p,q,s}]` command is running without any response on my comp for hours. This does not make a good impression.

Comment: The integration result you present is missing `r`. The correct result reads $2 \pi  \sin (\theta ) e^{i r s \cos (\theta )} J_0\left(\sqrt{p^2+q^2} r \sin (\theta )\right)$. Which version are you using? It can be further integrated over `r`. For instance, consider one partial case `Integrate[ E^(I r )  BesselJ[0, 2 r] , {r, 0,∞}]` yielding the perfectly finite answer $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: @yarchik: Thank you for your valuable comment. See my edit.

Comment: I completely disagree with your argument for $q=(1,1,1)$. In my answer below I explicitly show that integral is finite in this case.